# Logs not visible for nested batch files called from java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, spring, windows, batch-file, processbuilder

master batch file calls or starts other batch files. Invoking master batch file through java processBuilder. Got logs for the batch files "called" by master file but can't get logs for the batch files "started", because they are opened in a new cmd window.

**main.bat**

```
echo Hello World From main.bat
call first.bat
start second.bat
```

**first.bat**

```
echo Hello World From first.bat
```

**second.bat**

```
echo Hello World From second.bat
```

**job.getScript() in this case is "cd path\to\parent\folder \n main.bat"**

**runJob**

```
public void runJob(Job job) throws InterruptedException {
      ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe");
      Process process = null;
      try {
        process = processBuilder.start();
      } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
      BufferedWriter process_stdin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
      for(String command : job.getScript().split("\n")) {
        executeCommand(command, process_stdin);
      }
      executeCommand("exit", process_stdin);
      process_stdin.close();
      
      //Logs
      final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
      StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
      reader.lines().iterator().forEachRemaining(sj::add);
      System.out.println(sj.toString())
}
```

**executeCommand**

```
private void executeCommand(String command, BufferedWriter process_stdin) {
    try {
      // single execution
      process_stdin.write(command);
      process_stdin.newLine();
      process_stdin.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
```

logs

```
C:\>cd path\\to\\parent\\folder

path\\to\\parent\\folder>main.bat

path\\to\\parent\\folder>echo Hello World From main.bat 
Hello World From main.bat

path\\to\\parent\\folder>call first.bat 

path\\to\\parent\\folder>echo Hello World From first.bat 
Hello World From first.bat

path\\to\\parent\\folder>start second.bat 

path\\to\\parent\\folder>exit
```

Comment: in your main you say `call first.bat` and `start second.bat` where your log shows `call second.bat`. If it is `start` execution is outside of the original terminal and runs in it own.

Comment: @Gerhard
I changed the code for testing, it is originally "start second.bat"
And because start makes it open in new window, logs are not visible